# Is an Oracle 10g instance dependent on the windows account authentication?

Tags: oracle

I have created an Oracle 10g (10.2.0.4) instance on a Windows 2003 Server with a domain user xxx having domain administrator level privileges.

Now I wish to change xxx's password. Will it impact the oracle instance functioning?

Comment: Aside from you immediate question, it should be pointed out that 10.2 has been out of support for quite some time now.  And Windows Server 2003 extended support ended on July 14, 2015.  Makes one wonder why you are installing a museum piece.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Its an old installation and will phase out. However, its in production as of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle on Windows creates a service for database instances, called `OracleService%ORACLE_SID%`. By default, this service uses the `Local System` account so a password change of the installation user will not affect the database.

It is however possible and recommended to change the service user from `Local System` to a standard Windows account. If you performed this step, and you wish to change the password of that account, you must update the password in the service configuration.

[Managing Oracle Home User](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NTQRF/oh_usr.htm#NTQRF673)

> You can change the password using Windows tools. However, when you
>   change the password for this Windows User Account, you must also
>   update the password for all Oracle services running under the Windows
>   User Account.

Comment: Apart from services, does Oracle is binded to the specific Windows User and store the password anywhere within the db?

Answer (score 0):

The simple ans is No, it will not Effect until you have specified your user account in Oracle Service you can change the password by insuring it is not assigned to Local System